# How to "float" a capsule with a rigidbody component in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I've been stuck in a rut trying to figure this out for a while now. What I want is to have a capsule hover above the ground at a set height to eliminate ground friction and make irregular surfaces less of an issue. To do this though, I can't just set the position of a gameobject to a specific height because that looks a bit jittery and I want a physics-driven character, which means minimizing the amount of direct translation of position. Another approach would be applying a dampening force to force the player back up to the target height by applying a counterforce, which I can do, but cannot scale with the velocity of the player to make the character's rigidbody not hit the ground from high heights. I also tried modifying the velocity directly by adding a velocity to the negative falling velocity that stops at the minimum height

(something like this)

```
float correction = -rb.velocity.y * minheight/raydist;

rb.velocity += correction * upforce;
```

(`upforce` is a `Vector3.up`)

My logic for this is that as the player goes closer to the ground, the counter-velocity will approach the actual velocity, slowing the player to a stop at the minimum height. Not how it works though apparently.

I want to achieve a result where the player can have a smooth bounce after falling, and float at a set height over irregular surfaces and up slopes. If anyone knows how to do this, please help, and explain in as much detail as you can so that I may understand.